# Jupyter kernel dies trying to fit a Keras model with a custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

Both locally, and on the cloud (kaggle) the notebook dies (forgetting any imports or variables, stopping the execution of the cell) when trying to fit a Keras model. This issue is only present when the custom layer `SingularityExtractor2D` is present in the architecture.

You can find the notebook here:
[Github](https://github.com/MovsisyanM/digit-recognizer/blob/main/notebooks/SingularityExtractor.ipynb)

The custom callback `GateOfLearning` has been tested many times, working perfectly every time with any model architecture.
The notebook has been run on both the GPU and CPU, the problem persists.

Comment: You may check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576397/python-kernel-dies-on-jupyter-notebook-with-tensorflow-2) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110799/kernel-died-restarting-whenever-training-a-model) SO threads help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the `tf.ones` function, the shape must be `(spatial_0, ..., spatialN-1, in_channels, out_channels)` as opposed to the shape of the tensor that the layer gets when getting a call `(batch_size, spatial_0, ..., spatial_N-1, channels)`